# Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, java

Есть три Активити А, Б, и В
Первой запускается А, из нее в Б потом В, как сделать, что бы при нажатии назад, будучи в В, я попадал в А, минуя Б? и что бы Б и В были разрушены, при повторном нажатии назад приложение закрывалось!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует масса способов как повлиять на стек истории `Activity`. Например:

1. Пометить в манифесте активити Б - как `android:noHistory="true"` - тогда активити выпадет из истории
2. В активити В - написать: `public void onBackPressed() { moveTaskToBack(true);}`

Answer (score 2):

1. После startActivity();
   добавлять finish();